# CSS3 3D transforms and HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, webkit, css

Is it possible to create a html element inside a Canvas, draw it and than make it, for example rotate using CSS3?

And if it is, does it follow the Canvas settings (for example, lighting of some sort)?

Just a thing that popped into mind, might make an application i'm working on a lot lighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Any content inside `canvas` element is only displayed when `canvas` isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link](http://github.com/jamesu/csstransformexport) for a great Blender 2.6 output plugin that exports a CSS3 HTML page for viewing in your browser. I'm looking to also utilize Jmpress for presentation. http://sokra.github.com/jmpress.js/#/home

I'm using the Blender script now and it works very well (no crashing or freezing). The HTML produced displays fine, now I'm connecting Jmpress to get a final product.

Comment: Is this really answering the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can only use css3 operator in canvas and not inside canvas, in some element like img or div:
I think it's possible Look at:
http://christianheilmann.com/2011/09/05/animating-with-canvas-and-creating-css3-animations-with-javascript/